# ARM C++ compiler won't compile structure with volatile const member

Tags: c++, arm, microcontroller, keil

I'm trying to compile C++ code for an ARM MCU target, which includes a register definition header file. I'm getting the following errors:

```
test.h(18): error:  #294: invalid union member -- class "struct <unnamed>::<unnamed>::<unnamed>" has a disallowed member function
```

The error only occurs while compiling a C++ project, not with a C project.

It is caused by the `__IM` (`volatile const`) members of the following structure:

```
typedef struct {
  union {
    __IOM uint32_t VAR;

    struct {
      __IOM uint32_t BIT0  : 1;
      __IOM uint32_t BIT1  : 1;
      __IOM uint32_t BIT2  : 1;
      __IM  uint32_t TBD   : 13;
      __IOM uint32_t BIT17 : 1; 
    } VAR_b;
  } ;
} VAR_Type;
```

Here is explained why those `__IM` members are supposed to be `volatile const`, even in C++ :

http://www.keil.com/support/docs/3687.htm

I'm using Keil uVision with default ARM compiler:

```
*** Using Compiler 'V5.06 update 6 (build 750)', folder: 'C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCC\Bin'
```

I can't find what to do to solve this problem without hacking the `MCU.h` file to redefine `__IM` to `volatile` (not `volatile const`)

```
#undef __IM
#define __IM volatile
```

The addition of the previous code solved the problem and allowed me to compile but the `MCU.h` file that is provided by the MCU manufacturer isn't supposed to be modified, so I'd like to find a cleaner solution.

Comment: There is no line 18 in the codes you posted.

Comment: `volatile` and `const` at the same time seems a little *odd*, to say the least... Is that *really* what you want? What do you expect from that? If it's `volatile` it can change at any time, so it's not really `const`ant. If it's `const` then it says it will *not* change and `volatile` goes straight against that.. confused.

Comment: @JesperJuhl • when working with hardware registers right off the metal, the `const` marks the read-only registers, and the `volatile` tells the compiler not to make optimization assumptions.

Comment: @JesperJuhl -- a `const` register can't be modified by the program. It typically presents outside data, which can and will change, which is why it's `volatile`.

Comment: @PeteBecker That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more of the error message?  It says _"...has a disallowed member __function__..."_ what function ?

Comment: @JesperJuhl -- embedded programming is a different world. <g>

Comment: Switch to an unbroken compiler?

Comment: I had this experience before: Keil developers do **not** test their code enough. Apparently this header was never used for C++ in testing.

Comment: Is there any benefit in declaring the `TBD` member as `_IM` rather than `_IOM`? After all, the exact same bits are already declared `_IOM` in union member `VAR`. So the bits are both read-only and read-write at the same time?

Comment: is it an option to include `MCU.h` using `extern "C" {}` ?

Comment: switch to unbroken code.

Comment: How are you declaring your variable? Like `VAR_Type var;`?

This might be an initialization issue.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin sorry that's because I didn't reproduce the whole MCU.h file, just keeping the relevant extract

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta I didn't declare this variable, just included the MCU.h file

Comment: @old_timer + n.m : I have to keep the MCU.h file untouched, it has been provided by the MCU manufacturer so it has to work as is

Comment: @thebusybee what is strange is that in the page from the provided link the say that the __IM has been redefined to make it read only while copiling a C++ project, si it is supposed to work as is

Comment: @TarickWelling yes the option is here but the compiler error is here anyway

Comment: @RichardCritten this is the whole message....

Comment: as this code demonstrates you should think about using code from the mcu vendor vs rolling your own or using alternate libraries.   code like this is very compiler specific and will only be supported by the authors for the compilers specified. expect failure on any other compiler, if it doesnt fail then call it luck.

Comment: @old_timer I am actually trying to use the file that is provided by the manufacturer

Comment: g++ 7.4.0 fails to compile similar code.  Being `const`, the field requires a default intialiser or an initialiser in the default constructor.  Presumably deductions about default constructors etc ultimately lead to the 'disallowed member function' message.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to the Keil compiler, but under g++ 7.4.0, this struct generates an error not where it is defined, but where an instance of it is instantiated.

i.e.  The line

```
VAR_Type fred;
```

results in an error because the `const` member requires an initialiser (which, being a bitfield, cannot be specified as a default initialiser, and can therefore only be provided via a default constructor definition).

Are you instantiating this struct yourself? (At line 18, perhaps?)

If you are, and if you're doing so for a legitimate reason (e.g. for an in-memory copy of the hardware registers), there does seem to be a solution:

```
VAR_Type fred = { 0 };
```

compiles without error (at least using g++ 7.4.0).  (Note that this initialises the struct via the first member of the union.)

[EDITED TO ADD: A [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including full compiler command line would make it a lot easier for people to help you.]

Comment: If [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57871506/673852) is correct, your fix won't help.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't considered pre-C++11 compilation.  In any case, for C++11 upwards, even with -pedantic-errors g++ compiles, however clang++ (8.0.1) barfs, saying 'anonymous types declared in an anonymous union are an extension'.

Comment: Yes, this may become a show stopper if the compiler the OP chooses to switch to doesn't appear as lax as g++ is.

Answer (score 0):

The error you see resembles the most what g++ outputs when in C++03 mode. Namely, for the following code

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define __IOM volatile
#define __IM volatile const
typedef struct {
  union {
    __IOM uint32_t VAR;

    struct {
      __IOM uint32_t BIT0  : 1;
      __IOM uint32_t BIT1  : 1;
      __IOM uint32_t BIT2  : 1;
      __IM  uint32_t TBD   : 13;
      __IOM uint32_t BIT17 : 1; 
    } VAR_b;
  } ;
} VAR_Type;

int main()
{
    VAR_Type x={0};
}
```

I get the following compilation result:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -o test -pedantic-errors -std=c++03
test.cpp:15:7: error: member ‘<unnamed struct>::<unnamed union>::<unnamed struct> <unnamed struct>::<unnamed union>::VAR_b’ with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
     } VAR_b;
       ^~~~~
test.cpp:15:7: note: unrestricted unions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
```

The problem is that the structure inside the union doesn't have any copy assignment operator because it would be ill-formed (you can't assign to a `const` member). See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4049336/673852) for details. Since (I suppose) you can't edit the header, you may want to use a C++11-enabled compiler in C++11 mode. Not sure if Keil has one though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx a lot for your help !

I could reach ARM support. It seems that this is a real issue of incompatibility between the header files generated by their SVDconv tool and ARM compiler v5 (aka "armcc"). The solution is to build the project with ARM compiler v6 (aka "armclang").

Those structs are not to be user instanciated as they are plain C. They allow an easy access to the MCU registers. Here is an example of how they are declared in the  manufacturer provided header :

```
typedef struct {                                /*!< (@ 0x42000000) GPIOA Structure                                            */

  union {
    __IOM uint32_t CTRL;                        /*!< (@ 0x00000000) Control register                                           */

    struct {
      __IM  uint32_t RES        : 1;
      __IOM uint32_t RST        : 1;            /*!< [1..1] Soft reset                                                         */
      __IOM uint32_t INTEN      : 1;            /*!< [2..2] Interrupt enable                                                   */
    } CTRL_b;
  } ;

  union {
    __IOM uint32_t IRQPOLSET;                   /*!< (@ 0x00000004) Interrupt polarity set register                            */

    struct {
      __IOM uint32_t P0         : 1;            /*!< [0..0] Pin 0                                                              */
      __IOM uint32_t P1         : 1;            /*!< [1..1] Pin 1                                                              */
      __IOM uint32_t P2         : 1;            /*!< [2..2] Pin 2                                                              */
      __IOM uint32_t P3         : 1;            /*!< [3..3] Pin 3                                                              */
      __IOM uint32_t P4         : 1;            /*!< [4..4] Pin 4                                                              */
      __IOM uint32_t P5         : 1;            /*!< [5..5] Pin 5                                                              */
      __IOM uint32_t P6         : 1;            /*!< [6..6] Pin 6                                                              */
      __IOM uint32_t P7         : 1;            /*!< [7..7] Pin 7                                                              */
      __IOM uint32_t P8         : 1;            /*!< [8..8] Pin 8                                                              */
      __IOM uint32_t P9         : 1;            /*!< [9..9] Pin 9                                                              */
      __IOM uint32_t P10        : 1;            /*!< [10..10] Pin 10                                                           */
      __IOM uint32_t P11        : 1;            /*!< [11..11] Pin 11                                                           */
      __IOM uint32_t P12        : 1;            /*!< [12..12] Pin 12                                                           */
      __IOM uint32_t P13        : 1;            /*!< [13..13] Pin 13                                                           */
      __IOM uint32_t P14        : 1;            /*!< [14..14] Pin 14                                                           */
      __IOM uint32_t P15        : 1;            /*!< [15..15] Pin 15                                                           */
    } IRQPOLSET_b;
  } ;

  [etc...]

} GPIO_Type;
```

Here is an example of how the physical address of the first corresponding register is defined :

```
#define GPIOA_BASE                  0x41000000UL
```

And here is the link with the name the user will use in its code :

```
#define GPIOA                       ((GPIO_Type*)              GPIOA_BASE)
```

So then to access to bit P10 of the IRQPOLSET resister he does :

```
GPIOA->IRQPOLSET_b.P10
```